# Need help with ReturnUrl in MVC 3 LoginPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this url in my login view: http://localhost:5550/login?ReturnUrl=/forum/456&theme=1

I get the right url value when I am in the login page. 
As you can see I have 2 query string parameters: ReturnUrl and theme
So far good.

Now the login page posts a form to a controller action.
All I need is to read the values of these 2 query string params.
I just can't make it work.

This is my login page view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("try", "login"))
{
  //set text boxes and button so user can try login
}
```

This is my controller where I need those 2 values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Try(LoginModel model, string ReturnUrl, string theme)
{     
   //read all query string param values...but how?
   //I am not getting anything in string ReturnUrl, string theme. They are null
}
```

Other part of the question:

I can debug other controller. But not this controller. 
Is this because I am posting a form using BeginForm?
Doesn't make sense. But the breakpoint never hits even though I get error on browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't be reading from ReturnUrl. The flow works like this:

1. Request to controller action which requires authentication using the [Authorize] attribute
2. ASP.NET MVC adds the ReturnUrl and redirects to /Account/LogOn, automatically encoding and appending the ReturnUrl parameter
3. The Account/LogOn POST controller action, after authenticating the login information, redirects to the URL in the ReturnUrl.

I wrote about that in gory detail in the following posts:

- [Looking at how the ASP.NET MVC Authorize interacts with ASP.NET Forms Authorization](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/looking-at-how-asp-net-mvc-authorize-interacts-with-asp-net-forms-authorization.aspx)
- [Preventing Open Redirection Attacks in ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/01/25/preventing-open-redirection-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

The second post indicates one good reason why need to be careful with ReturnUrl - users can tamper with them.

In the example you showed above, I'd expect that, after authorization, the user would be redirected to the Forum / Index action, which would then be reading the values. If you are creating the ReturnUrl, you should be URL Encoding the second &.

Comment: Jon, You said MVC adds the returnurl and redirects to /Account/LogOn with auto encoding. Now how does MVC know what url to return to? Basically I have to redirect the user to the page where he clicked the LogIn link. The site has 100s of pages & user can click LogIn on any page. Some of these pages has their own query string as well.

Comment: Your case is when user tries to access some page which needs authentication. In that case MVC will know where to redirect. But in my case, I have different use case. I also need the previous use case as well i.e. redirect to originally requested page

Comment: RediredUrl should do exactly that - it should direct to the originally requested page. So if your ForumController had an [Authorize] attribute and the user browsed to /forum/456?theme=1, they'd be redirected to /Account/LogOn, after which they'd be redirected to forum/456?theme=1. Note that there's a question mark rather than an ampersand there.

Comment: I don't have LogOn action in my login controller. In that case do I need to rename my controller action to take advantage of that?

Comment: If you're writing your own account controller, I recommend at least referencing the AccountController that's included in the ASP.NET MVC 3 Internet project template.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the exact reason the values don't get bound, but the easy workaround is to add those properties to your login model and add hidden fields on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the decoration:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Try(LoginModel model, string ReturnUrl, string theme)
{     
   //read all query string param values...but how?
   //I am not getting anything in string ReturnUrl, string theme. They are null
}
```